# Название "->" и "." в C++

Tags: терминология, c++

Интересно, что в Рунете нет обсуждений, как правильно называть "->" и "." в C++ ;) . Предлагаю разместить эту информацию на этом форуме.

На https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580757/what-is-the-official-name-of-cs-arrow-operator большинство голосов - за название "->" arrow ("стрелка"), другие - за "structure pointer dereference operator" ("оператор обращения по указателю на структуру", поправьте, если можете придумать лучший перевод) и "member access operator" ("оператор доступа к члену класса/структуры").

Для разделения тогда, видимо, надо использовать "косвенный ..." и "прямой ..."?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В довольно популярной (насколько я знаю) книге Джеффа Элджера "C++ Библиотека программиста" они называются member selectors ("селекторы членов класса").

> Если вы назовете их «точкой» или
> «стрелкой» на семинаре с коктейлями,
> наступит гробовая тишина, все
> повернутся и презрительно посмотрят на
> вас, а в дальнем углу кто-нибудь
> выронит свой бокал.

Comment: А вообще-то, с такими снобами общаться стоит?

Comment: Ну, с людьми, которые все сущности называют хреньками, а процессы - безобразиями, тоже как-то не очень :) . Да и вообще, это всё-таки юмор ;)

Comment: @Михаил М, что юмор я вроде понял и насчет "такой фиговины" согласен, но и длинные наукообразные (как бы строгие) названия, которыми просто кишат кресты, это тоже, как-то не очень...

--

Ради интереса полистал "первоисточник" (K&R). 

Что интересно, названия для операций ``.'` и ``->'` в тексте почти не используются. Просто пишут `"... -> operation ..."` и т.п.

В одном месте увидел `arrow`, а еще в одном `structure member operator`.

Answer (score 3):

Селектор члена класса или структуры. Сильно лучше не придумаешь. Можно еще отметить, что это оператор.